# Difficulty in constructing SQL query for Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aggregation

I don't have much experience in SQL and I am finding difficult to construct the query for the following problem.

Let's say I have sales per month data as follows and is saved in Redshift

```
ProductId   Year    Month   Sales
A           2018    1       345
A           2018    2       3425
A           2018    3       56545
A           2018    4       234
A           2018    5       23
B           2018    1       645
B           2018    2       2324
B           2018    3       123
B           2018    4       700
B           2018    5       1410
....
....
....
```

I want to extract the following information from the above table. The query in plain English looks as follows.

1. Select the product (group by) where sales are greater than 800 for the month 2018/3. For this query, product "A" data should be returned with the sales value for month 2018/3
2. Select the product (group by) where the sale of month 2018/5 is 100% greater than 2018/4. Here only product "B" is matched and sales data of both months should be included in the result.

Edit: Expected result added.

For query 1

```
ProductId   Year    Month   Sales
A           2018    3       56545
```

For query 2 (Grouped)

```
ProductId   Increase    Year    Month   Sales
B           101.42 %    2018    5       1410
                        2018    4       700
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show the sample output you would expect from the input data you have shown?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Expected results added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query 1:** Select the product where sales are greater than 800 for the month 2018/3.

```
SELECT
  productid,
  year,
  month,
  sales
FROM table
WHERE year = 2018
  AND month = 3
  AND sales > 800
```

**Query 2:** Select the product where the sale of month 2018/5 is 100% greater than 2018/4.

```
SELECT
  productid
  a.year as previous_month_year,
  a.month as previous_month,
  a.sales as previous_month_sales,
  b.year as year,
  b.month as month,
  b.sales as sales,
  to_char(100 * b.sales / a.sales,'999D99%') as increase
FROM table a
JOIN table b
WHERE a.year = 2018
  AND b.year = 2018
  AND a.month = 4
  AND b.month = 5
  AND b.sales > a.sales * 2
  AND a.productid = b.productid
```

I'm not sure what you meant by "group by" in your requirements, since no aggregates are required.

Comment: Regarding group by - Maybe I didn't express the intent properly. The query would be "I need to know products (i.e., A, B, etc) who match the given condition. The condition would be dynamic combinations of "query 1" or "query 2"

For example: SELECT fields WHERE query_1_for(2018/3) AND query_1_for(2018/5) OR query_2_for(2018/4, 2018/6) AND so on.

Comment: I don't know how to think SQL way regarding above problem, but in my mind I thought query like this - each product has row for each months sales. So my thought was to group rows by product_id and inside each group appply the conditions. if all conditions are true select that product. I am imagining a tree structure here (Hang over from JSON / NO-SQL world)

Comment: The above queries should provide the expected output that you listed in your question. Are you now saying that this was _not_ the output that you actually wanted? If so, please update your question, or create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below queries

```
select * from tablename
where year=2018 and month=3 and and Sales>800

select * from tablename where year=2018 and month in (4,5)
and (case when year=2018 and month=5 then sales end)>(case when year=2018 and month=4 then sales end)*2
```

Comment: Regarding the second query. How to make comparisons where Product Id is same. For example, in the second query, sales of product A form month 2018/5 can get compared to product B sales form month 2018/4. But product A sales should be compared to itself in a different month.